# Mysql2::Error: View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause while running rails migration

Tags: mysql, sql

Using Rails migration (but doesn't matter). I was trying to create a view here, but I got

```
Mysql2::Error: View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause:
CREATE VIEW `lanciao` AS
```

when I try this:

```
create view lanciao as
  select
    subtime(payment.created_at, '0 5:0:0') as transaction_date,
    `order_item`.total_quantity,
    payment.amount as amount,
    `order`.payment_type
  from payments payment
  join orders `order` on `order`.id = payment.order_id
  left join donation_items donation on donation.order_id = `order`.id
  inner join (
    select order_id, sum(quantity) total_quantity 
    from order_items
    group by order_id
  ) `order_item` on `order`.id = `order_item`.order_id
  where payment.payment_state in ('settled', 'completed', 'captured', 'authorized', 'approved')
  and `order`.fixed_order_id is null
```

Without `create view lanciao`, I can run the `select` block to the end fine. I tried to refactor this, but couldn't get it working. How should I fix this?

Am also aware of separating this to different views and make reference to one another, but I wouldn't prefer this way.

Comment: separate each subquery in another view.

Answer (score 0):

The [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) state:

> Before MySQL 5.7.7, the SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause.

If you can upgrade to MySQL 5.7.7+ then you should be able to do exactly what you're trying to do.

Otherwise you might want to try creating a view of the subquery and then using that in your `FROM`.

So instead your SQL may look something like:

```
create view subquery_view as
  select order_id, sum(quantity) total_quantity 
  from order_items
  group by order_id

create view lanciao as
  select
    subtime(payment.created_at, '0 5:0:0') as transaction_date,
    `order_item`.total_quantity,
    payment.amount as amount,
    `order`.payment_type
  from payments payment
  join orders `order` on `order`.id = payment.order_id
  left join donation_items donation on donation.order_id = `order`.id
  inner join subquery_view as `order_item` on `order`.id = `order_item`.order_id
  where payment.payment_state in ('settled', 'completed', 'captured', 'authorized', 'approved')
  and `order`.fixed_order_id is null
```

Be aware that nesting views inside each other can cause performance issues but I'm unaware of an alternative approach.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I don't want to create separate views.

Comment: Then, as the docs state, you're screwed. Your other options are to transform your database, pull the subquery to the client and mash that together in memory on the client or use another RDBMS that might support a subquery inside the FROM in a view. They're all worse/more painful options than a nested view in my opinion but it's up to you.

Comment: If updating MySql to MySql 5.7 is an option, this restriction is lifted.  "Before MySQL 5.7.7, the SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause." source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html

Comment: @ErikBlessman that's neat, I hadn't spotted that. I've added it to my answer.